# How is the VS performance profiles increasing the performance?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, c++-cli

So ready with my new c++/cli dll for deserializing html to oo elements, I went ahead to test the performance. The benchmark was some random stackoverflow page saved in a file to be processed 1000 times. The dll is called from a vb.net test app. In debug mode it takes ~15ms per page, in release mode ~2.9ms but when I ran the performance profiler on release mode, surprisingly I got ~1.5ms.

How is that possible? That is nearly half the time. Is it using some performance increasing compiler options or something?

Comment: Code that strongly depends on the cost of I/O has very unpredictable execution time.  It will be very fast when the file data is stored in the file system cache, slow when it needs to be read from the disk.

Comment: that's not it, the file is read into a char* before the timer starts.

Comment: Did you use "Profile Guided Optimization"?  Or the same build is running faster when the profiler is active?

Comment: No optimization as far as I'm aware of, just selected Analyze -> Performance and diagnostics -> start performance wizard -> cpu sampling -> finish

Comment: Fixed a memory leak and did some optimization in the process, now down to 1.5ms in release, 0.7ms in release while running performance analyzer. Still don't understand how or why.